# Eclipse android ddms loading error

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

When I start eclipse I get this error:

```
 [2011-10-26 22:57:41 - ddms]Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
```

I have tried shutting off my firewall, my a/v, loading the emulator before starting eclipse, loading the emulator while eclipse is loaded and then restarting eclipse, killing/stopping abd server and then restarting. The last and final thing that I can think of is that I am using a 64 bit machine, but I downloaded the 32 bit versions of the jdk and eclipse. Would this be the reason? On my xp machine it works (it's a 32 bit machine). help!!! thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know if I should worry about this error.
I haven't noticed any problems, but I don't like seeing this error.

Comment: I forgot about this. I never got a resolution, but it turned out that it was the firewall. The problem is with agnitum outpost firewall. There are work arounds with different versions (and different vendor firewalls), but I could not get it to work on Windows 7 x64. Very strange because it works on Windows XP. The solution would be to submit a ticket to them and see if they can help or install another firewall. I just using my xp for development for now. You can't deploy with this error, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem in fact was the firewall agnitum outpost firewall. And the problem is on both Windows 7 64 and 32 bit systems (although mine was professional, so I can't say if all versions would have the same problem..I would imagine so). On windows xp there were no problems. I found a lot of solutions online that addressed the issue, but on other versions of their product (not their free versions). I tried to apply those, but none worked. I finally uninstalled and tried out Comodo Firewall and I haven't had any problems. So that's my solution hopefully someone will find this info useful and not spend months trying to figure out why it will not work. Now I can work on both computers.